# sections in position/ getboundingclientrect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the position of sections in viewport & adding an active class to them, but the code does not work. can anyone help pls?

```
// Get the position of the sections in viewport

function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }

//add active class to sections in viewport
 function setActiveClass(){
    for (let i=0; i <= sectionsArr.length; i++){
        if (isInViewport(sections[i])){
            sections[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        }else{
            sections[i].classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
let sectionsArr = Array.from(sections);


function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }



 function setActiveClass(){
    for (let i=0; i < sectionsArr.length; i++){
        if (isInViewport(sectionsArr[i])){
            sectionsArr[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        }else{
            sectionsArr[i].classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    }}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}

.filler{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background:#db9292;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}



.your-active-class{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="filler">
    <p class="button" onclick="setActiveClass()" >Click me!</div>
   </div>
    <section class="secs">Section1</section>
    <section class="secs">Section2</section>
    <section class="secs">Section3</section>
    <section class="secs">Section4</section>
   <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess you should change your "sections[i]" to "sectionsArr[i]" in your for loop and change the " i <= sectionsArr.length " to only "i < sectionsArr.length"

```
function setActiveClass(){
    for (let i=0; i < sectionsArr.length; i++){
        if (isInViewport(sectionsArr[i])){
            sectionsArr[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        }else{
            sectionsArr[i].classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried all variations between sections & sectionsArr but still not detecting the class, but can't detect where the problem is

Comment: Look again on the answer, you did a small error with the for loop. (change the i<= to a i<)

Comment: I changed it still not detecting the class

Comment: What do you mean with detecting, you somewhere need a htmlCollectionArray with all your section you wanna check. `document.getElementsByClassNames("yourclassname")`

Comment: i mean linking the class with the html sections

Comment: ``` const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const sectionsArr = Array.from(sections); ```

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something else, so we have your whole code? Or at least a minimal reconstruction?

Comment: yes sure! I appreciate ur help  https://codepen.io/menna-rihan/pen/oNLzzeg

Comment: but the nav menu is not showing in the codepen but it appears in all browsers

Comment: In the CodePen you accidently added the js double, but the error is: You never call the function itself. Your code works perfectly, but you never call the function (In this code pen at least, i just added a simple onscroll event, and its working just fine) `window.onscroll = ()=>{
  setActiveClass();
};`

Comment: yes that was the mistake. thank you so much, I'm a beginner in Javascript and need alot of practice. I appreciate your it that you took the time to help out.

Comment: Youre welcome! And dont worry, you dont need to be an beginner to forget to actually call a function. Its just that simple that you dont think about it.